# Learning Bash - How to declare and print/embed variables properly?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

I'm trying to write a bash script to automatically copy files from my build and source directory (which has a shared object binary) to my system `/usr/lib` and `/usr/include` directories, respectively.

When I run the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

RELEASE_ARG = "--release"
DEBUG_ARG   = "--debug"

DEST_NAME = "libEngine.so"

SRC_NAME = "libEngineSO.so"

ENGINE_DBG_DEST = "/usr/lib/Stitches/Debug/$DEST_NAME"
ENGINE_REL_DEST = "/usr/lib/Stitches/Release/$DEST_NAME"

ENGINE_REL_SRC = "$STITCH_ROOT/Engine__Release/$SRC_NAME"
ENGINE_DBG_SRC = "$STITCH_ROOT/Engine__Debug/$SRC_NAME"

if [ ! -z $1 ]; then 
    #foo
    echo "No argument specified; please specify either ${RELEASE_ARG} or $DEBUG_ARG. K BAI\n"
    exit
elif [ -z $1 -eq RELEASE_ARG ]; then
    #wat
    echo "If you actually chose this option, you better be damn ready to distribute...\n"
    echo "Updating Release directory in $ENGINE_REL_DEST\n"

    cp $ENGINE_REL_SRC $ENGINE_REL_DEST

elif [ -z $1 -eq DEBUG_ARG ]; then
    #reasonable and realistic
    echo "Good choice...\n"
    echo "Updating Debug directory in $ENGINE_DBG_DEST\n"
    cp $ENGINE_DBG_SRC $ENGINE_DBG_DEST
fi

echo "Sex ;)"
```

I get this output:

```
x@x ~/Programming/Stitches-Qt/scripts $ sh postbuild.sh --debug
postbuild.sh: 3: postbuild.sh: DEBUG: not found
postbuild.sh: 5: postbuild.sh: RELEASE_ARG: not found
postbuild.sh: 6: postbuild.sh: DEBUG_ARG: not found
postbuild.sh: 8: postbuild.sh: DEST_NAME: not found
postbuild.sh: 10: postbuild.sh: SRC_NAME: not found
postbuild.sh: 12: postbuild.sh: ENGINE_DBG_DEST: not found
postbuild.sh: 13: postbuild.sh: ENGINE_REL_DEST: not found
postbuild.sh: 15: postbuild.sh: ENGINE_REL_SRC: not found
postbuild.sh: 16: postbuild.sh: ENGINE_DBG_SRC: not found
No argument specified; please specify either  or . K BAI
```

As you can see I must be using the variables improperly or something. How do I accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

P.S., and I know I can't do this unless I'm root, so I made a subdirectory in `/usr/lib` | `/usr/include` so I could just chown that to my username. So, this should work...

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use arbitrary whitespace in bash.

```
RELEASE_ARG="--release"
DEBUG_ARG="--debug"
```

You should quote when using `test`.

```
if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now when I try to pass `--debug` to the script, it just fails. Is there anything else I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Yes test between right brakets should be just = instead of-eq also use $ symbol to get the variable expansion between double quotes is more safe also -z must be removed, for further info `man bash`

Comment: To clarify @Nahuel's comment, your elif's should look like this: `elif [ "$1" = "$RELEASE_ARG" ]; then`